# Is there another name for a suspension that creates a chord in the given key?

Tags: harmony, chord-theory, terminology, nonchord-tones

Here's a progression of a German 6th chord to V in C minor:

[image: Augmented 6th to V progression]

But that creates parallel perfect fifths between the alto and bass(Ab-G, Eb-D). Since I'm lazy, instead of fixing that, I cover it up with a suspension(I think that's legal):

[image: Augmented 6 to V with suspension]

Here is where my question lies. The second example briefly creates chord III+ in the harmonic minor set. Is there a different name for this situation where a suspension creates another chord in the given key?

Comment: The most common CPP method for avoiding parallels would be to make the B in your second measure into a C. This gives G-C-E-G (in open position), a c64 chord that moves smoothly to G-B-D-G your actual list chord. The i64 is often a nice interpolation. (It can be thought of as a G chord with C and E being suspended into D and B in the final G chord. ) You could even end smoothly with a G7 (and go to either c or Ab or a or A or make G7 and new German Sixth and go to F#64 and thence to C# and F#, etc.

Comment: Are your first two staves supposed to be treble and bass? Sure, I can put the pieces together, but why would you crop the clefs in one example, but not the second?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of traditional counterpoint, there are two types of suspensions. The first is what we normally think of: where the suspended tone is a dissonant tone not a member of the current chord.

The second type is what we call a "consonant suspension," in which case the suspended tone creates a consonant interval above the bass. Often times this consonant interval is a sixth above the lowest pitch that then resolves down to a perfect fifth.

Having said all of this, I very much view your final chord as V with a non-chord tone E♭. Augmented-sixth chords are predominants that resolve to dominants, and the rarity of III+ (let alone in first inversion!) really prevents us from hearing this chord as a mediant. As such, I view this E♭ as a suspension, albeit a pretty rare one.

I'll also say that Mozart, of all people, had these parallel fifths in Ger+6–V resolutions all the time. Other composers typically solved this by going to a cadential six-four chord, where the B of the V chord is delayed by C, as ttw mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Can you cite some examples of Mozart pieces with these parallel fifths?

Comment: @phoog: The examples are well-known enough that this particular type of +6 resolution is sometimes referred to as "Mozart fifths."  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecutive_fifths#Mozart_fifths). I should note I always treat claims about "vast majority" with some skepticism regarding frequency in theory textbooks, as I've seen quite a few instances over the years of theory textbooks saying something is more "common" or "rare" or whatever, when actual practice in historical compositions suggests otherwise. Regardless, this type of +6 resolution does occur sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. But I wonder if the idea really just contrasts the contrapuntal thinking of suspension with the harmonic thinking of chord.

I think the common case is the contrapuntal idea of a double suspension or appoggiatura over a dominant bass. Ex. bass of `G` with `C` and `E` in the upper voices forming as `6/4` figure. Contrapuntally that is an double suspension/appoggiatura, and from the old figured bass harmony perspective it would be a harmonization of the dominant, a dominant type harmony. If you were to label that with a Roman numeral, it would be a `V`, and actually some types of Roman numeral analysis will label the chord `V6/4`. From the perspective of chords, and chord root theory, the modern view of harmony, it is a second inversion tonic chord, and in Roman numeral analysis it is `I6/4`.

So, a particular vertical stack of pitches may be called either `V6/4` or `I6/4` mostly depending on whether you regard the upper voices in contrapuntal terms of a suspension/appoggiatura or as chord tones in an inverted chord.

I don't think that is really the idea you have in mind, but I think it's related, because your particular example involves a chord whose identity is complicated by inversion issues.

You want to say that the chord is `III+6/3` in `C` minor, tones `G B Eb`.

The basic mediant chord in a minor key is `III`, a major triad, in `C` minor tones `Eb G Bb`.

The mediant triad is probably the tonally weakest chord. It's modal so it doesn't do much to establish a tonal center. Inverting it and then altering it to an augmented triad will make it tonally even murkier.

Your augmented chord is *symmetrical*, meaning all the inversions are enharmonically the same, which makes the root ambiguous. You could say that the chord is a `G` augmented triad. That would regard the progression as `Gr+ V` decorated with a suspension. I think that is clearer than `Gr+ III+6/3 V`. Also, I don't think the progression really sounds like it involves a mediant chord so `Gr+ V` also sounds right.

As pointed out in comments, the common way to avoid the parallel fifths is the use a double suspension, and do `Gr+ i6/4 V`.

Answer (score -2):

A suspension, by definition, creates a dissonance in the following chord.<sup>1</sup> Since in this case the held note from the `Ger6` chord becomes a consonance in the following `III+` chord, there is no suspension — just a tied note.

---

<sup>1.</sup> "**Suspension.** A form of discord arising from the holding over of a note in one chord as a momentary part of the chord which follows, it then resolving by falling a degree to a note which forms a real part of the second chord." (*The Oxford Companion to Music*, ed. Alison Latham, 2002)

Comment: The diminished fourth isn't dissonant?

Comment: @phoog It's a chord tone, so technically not dissonant against the chord.

Comment: So the diminished fifth in a diminished triad or dominant seventh chord isn't dissonant?  The seventh in a seventh chord isn't dissonant?  What definition does the Oxford Companion give for "dissonant"?  I am sure that it includes diminished fourths in any context.

Comment: @phoog Perhaps "dissonant" is misleading. A suspension is a non-chord tone. It's not that a diminished interval isn't dissonant in itself, it's that it's part of the chord rather than "dissonant" against the chord itself.

Comment: No, a suspension is not necessarily a "non-chord tone"; it is, as your definition states, a dissonant tone.  The concept predates chords by centuries.  Whether a tone is or isn't a non-chord tone is meaningless because you can decide that the chord is one that includes the tone or is another that doesn't.  "Against the chord itself" is not helpful: for example, a dominant seventh chord is a dissonant chord, and its seventh may be prepared and resolved as a suspension from the preceding ii or IV chord (which is one of the ways dominant seventh chords came to be).

Comment: The 1st sentence: surely the dissonance is in the sus chord itself, which resolves to consonance in the *following* chord? Ah, do you mean it makes the following chord  into a dissonant chord which then gets resolved? Awkward to explain!